# writing a bash array (of strings and special chars) to a file

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash array `OUTARRAY` that I fill will values from processing an `INARRAY`. I frequently append to `OUTARRAY` special chars, namely `\t` and `\n`
so it may look like:

```
OUTARRAY[j]="\n"
```

or

```
OUTARRAY[j]="${INARRAY[i]}\t"
```

in the end I dump the `OUTARRAY` in a file using

```
printf "%s" "${OUTARRAY[@]}" > ${OUTFILE}
```

the result I get however is, a single line file with all the special chars printed within:

```
\n2771\t2899\t7624\t2911\t\n2772\t2904\t7706\t2911\t\n2771\t2909
```

Instead, I want columned output. Something like

```
2771    2899    7624    2911
2772    2904    7706    2911
```

and so on.
what do I do wrong? 
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` does not interpret C-style backslash escapes (`\n`) in quoted strings.

Instead, use the `bash` syntax `$'\n'`:

```
OUTARRAY[j]=$'\n'
OUTARRAY[j]="${INARRAY[i]}"$'\t'
```

You might find it more readable if you start by defining:

```
NL=$'\n'
TAB=$'\t'
```

and then you can insert `${NL}` and `${TAB}` freely inside your double-quoted strings.

---

Alternatively, you can use a bash extension:

`printf` normally expands C-style backslash escapes in formats, but not in arguments. However, if you are using bash, then you can use the bash-specific `%b` `printf` format which expands backslash escapes in the corresponding argument. I don't really endorse this solution, but it should work without other modifications:

```
printf "%b" "${OUTARRAY[@]}" > ${OUTFILE}
```

---

By the way, it is not really good style to use ALL CAPS for bash variable names, because it increases the probability that they will clash with bash/system-specific environment variables.

Comment: Oh, it seems we have exactly the same answer... so I can only `+1` yours `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf There are not so many ways to answer the question :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of inserting the string `\t` or `\n`, insert actual tabs and newlines:

```
outarray[j]=$'\n'
outarray[j]=${inarray[i]}$'\t'
```

Now this is not really a good strategy. Instead, do not put your formatting in the array, but use `printf` to format how you want your array to be displayed: if you want 4 fields per line, separated by tabs:

```
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "${outarray[@]}"
```

(btw, I lowercased your variable names, it's much better).

Comment: for reasons of parsing strength, I prefer not to assume I'll always have 4 columns :) this would be a good way otherwise.

Comment: @nass: you can build your format string dynamically to take that into account!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are the *right way to do it* but it is possible to print your data as it is. You can use `echo -ne` and a loop to print your values:

```
$ arr=( "a\t" "b\n" "c\t" "d\n" )
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo -ne $i; done
a       b
c       d
```

The `-n` switch to `echo` removes the trailing newline and the `-e` means that backslash escape characters will be interpreted.

Comment: Yes, that's another quick possibility too! (with caveats too). `+1` anyways. `:)`.

Comment: As gniourf_gniourf notes, `printf` is much more elegant if you have a consistent number of columns.

Comment: I readily acknowledge that both of your alternatives are superior, I just thought that `echo` deserved a mention. +1 to both of you.